# Improving efficiency in iterating over list sets in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of lists that has items in element 0 and value associated with it in element 1. Each item could appear more than once. I would like to create a list of uniques items with the max value associated with each one. My code accomplishes this, but seems very inefficient. Also, this is a simplified example. `mylist` could be 100,000 rows. Any suggestions of improving efficiency?

```
mylist = [['Item 1', 12],['Item 1', 10], ['Item 3', 12],['Item 4', 10], ['Item 3', 14]]

# get unique items
my_unique_items = list(set(x[0] for x in mylist))

# make it a list of list
my_unique_items = [[x] for x in my_unique_items]

# iterate over list items
for item in my_unique_items:

    # do list comp to get max value and append
    item.append(max([x[1] for x in mylist if x[0] == item[0]]))

print my_unique_items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more efficient to only loop through `mylist` once.  If you only care about the max value for each item key, just keep a mapping of items and their max values and compare them as you go through the list.

This has a worst case of O(n), whereas your original had a worst case of O(n^2).

```
item_maxes = {}
for item in mylist:
    max_value = item_maxes.setdefault(item[0], None)
    if max_value is None or item[1] > max_value:
        item_maxes[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Edit: I think [ShadowRanger's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35046572/1547004) version of this method is much cleaner looking:

> ```
> max_vals = {}
> for item, value in mylist:
>     max_vals[item] = max(max_vals.get(item, value), value)
> ```

Comment: Note that the last line should assign item[1] to the item_maxes dict, not item[0[

Comment: I tested all the loops over 1,000,000 rows. Mine took 18 seconds, yours was the fastest at .4 seconds so I chose it as best answer. @shadowranger was .6 seconds

Comment: @user2242044: Not wholly surprising; the costs to use `.get` and `max` every run of the loop are a lot higher than you might expect. Amusingly, stupid hacks like caching bound methods and built-in functions to more local scope will end up changing the performance quite a bit, e.g. adding: `max_vals_get = max_vals.get` and `_max = max` just outside the loop, then doing: `max_vals[item] = _max(max_vals_get(item, value), value)` would likely reduce runtime for large inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If the inputs are already sorted (or you want the outputs sorted), and nice way to do this is with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from future_builtins import map  # On Python 2.x only, to get generator based map

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

# Nicer names, and avoid recreating getvalue on each loop
getitem, getvalue = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1)

# If not already sorted, must sort by same key we're grouping on:
mylist.sort(key=getitem)

max_vals = [(k, max(map(getvalue, g))) for k, g in groupby(mylist, key=getitem)]
```

If you don't care about order, and your items are hashable, a `dict` is generally going to be faster (it might use slightly more memory if most `items` are unique):

```
max_vals = {}
for item, value in mylist:
    max_vals[item] = max(max_vals.get(item, value), value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the `itertools` module and [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) from the the `operator` module.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = {}
>>> for g, data in groupby(sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0)):
...     d[g] = max(list(zip(*data))[1])
... 
>>> d
{'Item 1': 12, 'Item 3': 14, 'Item 4': 10}
```

You can also using the [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead of using the `list` constructor and normal slice operation.

```
>>> for g, data in groupby(sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0)):
...     d[g] = max(*islice(zip(*data),  1, None))
... 
>>> d
{'Item 1': 12, 'Item 3': 14, 'Item 4': 10}
```